# It is possible to change the icon theme on a remastered live cd?

Tags: 11.10, gnome-fallback

writing a *.override file in /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas doesn change anything.
If i edit the xml file the system will crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done this before for [Demi Lovato Linux](http://demilovato.sf.net)

look [here](http://sf.net/projects/demilovato) are some files labeled root, It contains the configs and everything for reference.

for this you edit this file `/var/lib/gconf/debian.defaults`

look for this line

```
<entry name="icon_theme" mtime="1323406457" type="string">
                <stringvalue>Demi_Lovato</stringvalue>
            </entry>
```

Comment: Thx but this configuration file change nothing )= . Perhaps it is a solution to overwrite the ubuntu theme.

Comment: it works now :  [link] (http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/692/screenshotbac.png)

Comment: Wow that's Ubuntu, it looks like windows. also a nether trick is copying the configs from the home folder to /etc/skel/  for example /home/$USER/.gconf to /etc/skel/.gconf